# jquery javascript check for the duplication in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I need to change the array format and check for the duplication in the array where key will be same. If same key exists then I have get values of the keys

```
              var selectedItems = ["Group1", "Group1"] ;

                  if (arrHasDupes(selectedItems)) // this just calls the function to test it
                    {
                        alert('duplicates found');
                        // $(this).prop("checked", false);
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //alert('no duplicates found');
                        // $(this).prop("checked", true);
                    }

                    function arrHasDupes(A) {
                        // finds any duplicate array elements using the fewest possible comparison
                        var i, j, n;
                        n = A.length;
                   // to ensure the fewest possible comparisons
                        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { // outer loop uses each item i at 0 through n
                            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) { // inner loop only compares items j at i+1 to n
                                if (A[i] == A[j])
                                    return true;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
```

I need change array to

```
      var selectedItems = ["Group1:123", "Group1:564"] 
         if(group1[i] ==group1[j])
        {

        return group1[i];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `group1[i].split(':')[0] === group2[j].split(':')[0]`?

Comment: Yes i tired using split function

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear from the question and from your comments below what result you're looking for, but you've said you need to know which values are duplicated, and what the duplicate values are, so here's a way to do that — adjust it as needed:

If the things you're comparing are strings or readily converted to strings, I usually use a flag object for this, something like this:

```js
// Returns an object keyed by the "GroupX" string.
// Each entry is an array of the duplicate values
// for that key.
function findDuplicateGroups(a) {
  var singles = {};
  var duplicates = {};
  a.forEach(function(entry) {
    var parts, key, value, dups;
    
    // Get the parts of the entry
    // The `key` and `value` vars are just for clarity
    parts = entry.split(":");
    key = parts[0];
    value = parts[1];
    
    // Have we seen this key before?
    if (singles.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      // Yes, get the duplicates array for the key if any
      dups = duplicates[key];
      if (!dups) {
        // New duplicate, add an entry with the two
        // values we've seen so far
        duplicates[key] = [singles[key], value];
      } else {
        // Existing duplicate, add this entry
        dups.push(value);
      }
    } else {
      // First entry we've seen for this key
      singles[key] = value;
    }
  });
  return duplicates;
}

// An array that does have duplicates
var yes = [
  "Group1:111",
  "Group2:111",
  "Group3:111",
  "Group1:222", // Duplicate in group 1
  "Group2:222", // Duplicate in group 2
  "Group1:333"  // Duplicate in group 1
];

var yesDups = findDuplicateGroups(yes);
var yesKeys = Object.keys(yesDups);
snippet.log("'yes' array has " + yesKeys.length + " dups");
yesKeys.forEach(function(key) {
  snippet.log("* " + key + ": " + yesDups[key].join(", "));
});

// An array that doesn't
var no = [
  "Group1:111",
  "Group2:111",
  "Group3:111"
];

var noDups = findDuplicateGroups(no);
var noKeys = Object.keys(noDups);
snippet.log("'no' array has " + noKeys.length + " dups");
noKeys.forEach(function(key) {
  snippet.log("* " + key + ": " + noDups[key].join(", "));
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi need to return duplicate value where values will be different with same key

Comment: @user1578849: So you mean you have things like `{key: "foo", value: 42}` and `{key: "foo", value: 67}` and you need to return...what? 42? 67? An array containing both? The question's pretty unclear. What if multiple keys are duplicated, do you return an array of arrays? Or an object keyed by the key and with arrays of duplicate values?

Comment: @user1578849: Separately: Are your entries *really* strings in the form `Group1:123`? If so, is `Group1` the key and `123` the value?

Comment: @user1578849: And the answers to all the other questions above are...?!

Comment: i have not tired with array of array. currently i m getting duplication but with that i need to values so that i can change the color of tht div

Comment: There's still a problem with keys such as 'hasOwnProperty'
and '\_\_proto__', and generally messing about with `Object.prototype`. Granted, this is a pretty unlikely scenario, but not impossible. Using `var flags = Object.create(null);`, prefixing `entry.key` with e.g. '#', and removing the `hasOwnProperty` check will help.

Comment: @mintsauce: :-) Oddly enough, that's what I usually do -- although I use "x" (I like "#" though). In practice, though, as you say, really unlikely.

Comment: @user1578849: It's still really unclear what you want as an end result, but I've updated the answer showing one way to get one kind of result with the information, you can adapt it from there. Best,